# create Module for the Product Out of stock notification

Tags: magento-1.9

with refered (https://github.com/Apptha/Out-Of-Stock-Notification)
but now problem is my entered data on product page not fetch in database no any entry in database table Plz give me some solution 
I get particular solution is fetched Product_id,Product_name,Email,etc.. in database magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the connection_resource that connect with database? Also please make sure you are fetching from correct table